# How do I make jqgrid columns sort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

The columns do not sort.

I've tried changing the datatype to local and adding loadonce: true. Columns are set to sortable: true and I've tried setting sorttype to string and text, neither work. I'm using JQGrid version 4.5.2.

```
var grid = jQuery("#AgencyQuotesGrid");
grid.jqGrid({
    url: '/Admin/QuotesGrid',
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'myAltRowClass',
    autowidth: false,
    datatype: 'local',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Agency', 'Agency Name', 'Quote Number', 'Insured Name', 'Product', 'Status', 'Effective Date', 'Last Update'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'AgencyCode', index: 'AgencyCode', width: 6, align: 'left', sortable: true, sorttype: 'string', stype: 'text', classes: 'defaultpointer' },
        { name: 'AgencyName', index: 'AgencyName', width: 11, align: 'left', sortable: true, classes: 'defaultpointer' },
        { name: 'QuoteCode', index: 'QuoteCode', width: 6, align: 'left', sortable: true, classes: 'defaultpointer' },
        { name: 'InsuredName', index: 'InsuredName', width: 11, align: 'left', sortable: true, classes: 'defaultpointer' },
        { name: 'PackageTypeCode', index: 'PackageTypeCode', width: 7, align: 'left', sortable: true, classes: 'defaultpointer' },
        { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 3, align: 'left', formatter: changeToolTip, classes: 'defaultpointer' },
        { name: 'EffectiveDate', index: 'EffectiveDate', width: 7, align: 'left', classes: 'defaultpointer' },
        { name: 'UpadateDate', index: 'UpadateDate', width: 7, align: 'left', classes: 'defaultpointer'}],
    height: '100%',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20, 20, 50],
    sortname: "EffectiveDate",
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    imgpath: "../../Content/Images/",
    caption: '',
    loadonce: true,
    pager: "#AgencyQuotesPager",
    emptyrecords: "No quotes have been submitted",
    onSelectRow: function (ids) {
        $.cookie('lasttab', $('#subTabs').tabs('option', 'selected'), { expires: 1 });
        if (ids != null) {
            var data = $("#AgencyQuotesGrid").getRowData(ids);
            $("#AgencyQuotesGrid").trigger(window.location.href = '/Admin/QuoteRouter/?id=' + data.AgencyCode + '&code=' + data.QuoteCode + '&type=' + encodeURIComponent(data.PackageType))
        }
    },
    loadComplete: function () { $("#AgencyQuotesGrid").setGridWidth($('#AgencyQuotesContainer').width() - 40, true), $('.ui-jqgrid').css('font-size', 14); jQuery("#AgencyQuotesGrid").trigger("reloadGrid"); },
    onSortCol: function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
        var col = $("#grid_summarygrid").getGridParam('colNames');
        var label = "Ordered by " + col[columnIndex] + " " + sortOrder + "ending";

        $("#gridsort").text(label);
    }
}).navGrid($('#AgencyQuotesPager'), { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true });
});
```

I expect the columns to sort, but they are not. The column arrows change and the grid pops up the "loading..." but nothing changes. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadComplete` is triggered every time the grid loads, which includes local loads, sorting, pagination, etc. You registered an event handler which then immediately reloads the grid (by calling `trigger("reloadGrid")`) which causes the grid to clear itself and revert to its initial state. Remove the `reloadGrid` trigger and it should respect the client-side sorting.

```
loadComplete: function () {
    [...]
    jQuery("#AgencyQuotesGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried a couple of different things and that was one of the things I saw. For anyone seeing this answer I didn't need the onSortCol either.